# PHP return value to div value

Tags: php, javascript, echo, innerhtml, setinterval

Hello i am having trouble with passing a php return value to the innerHTML method to change my div's value on a fixed interval.

this is my code, i inclue the php file containing the method, and then create an object of the class containing the method, then i want to echo the return value to the innerHTML function. but is does not work.

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "\
    <? include_once("php/functions.php");         \
       $cont = new Content();                     \
       echo ($cont->getPosts());                  \
    ?>";
}, 1000);
```

However this works so a php value can be echod to the innerHTML function.

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<? echo "Some Text"; ?>";
}, 1000);
```

there is noting wrong with the  `<? include_once("php/functions.php"); $cont = new Content(); echo ($cont->getPosts());?>` statement, because when i put it outside of the `<script>` tags it does what it needs to, however it does not refrech every few seconds

thanks in advance
i tried to make the question as clear as possible, if you have questions however, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you mean by "does not work" is that it only puts the same thing out every second. This is because PHP is run on the server-side BEFORE the browser gets any HTML, and this makes the code look something like this when it arrives to the browser:

```
var t = setInterval(function(){document. getElementById("content"). innerHTML = "whatever php produced";}, 1000);
```

This means that your browser will just put the static text "whatever php produced" into your div every time the interval fires.

To solve this you will need a slightly different approach. Use AJAX to request an updated version from a PHP script that return just what is suppoesd to be inside the div. jQuery has a function to do this for you if you are not familiar with AJAX yourself.

```
var t = setInterval( function(){$( '#content' ).load( '/url/to/serverside/script.php' )}, 1000 );
```

Also be aware that AJAX is asynchronous, meaning static timing is a bad idea. Instead you should use a on-complete function to fire the next load.

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load( '/url/to/serverside/script.php', function( r, s, x ) {
          setTimeout( loadContent, 1000 );
    });
}

loadContent();
```

The server-side script can be something like what you originally had:

```
<?
include_once("php/functions.php");
$cont = new Content();
echo ($cont->getPosts());
?>
```

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/load/